# css for dropdown selector

Tags: css

I'm not a web developer by any stretch of the imagination, I get things to the way I want them basically thru trial and lots of error. I can't seem to figure this one out.
I want to change the style of my dropdown selector from using the default OS styling to a suitable style I found but I can't figure out what goes where.
Here is my existing dropdown selector css:

```
/* select
    ==========================================================*/
.selector, .selector * {
/* margin: 0;
  padding: 0; */
}
.selector select:focus { outline: 0; }

div.selector {
 /* background-position: -490px -24px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 2px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;

  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); */
}
  div.selector span {
 /* background-position: 100% 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 27px 0px 7px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #000;
    white-space: nowrap; */
  }
  div.selector select {
    /*background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: none;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  text-transform:none;*/
  font-size:12px;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  }

div.selector, div.selector span {

  /*background-repeat: no-repeat;
  line-height: 24px; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
    background-image: url("sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    line-height: 24px;*/

}
div.selector, div.selector span, div.selector select { /*height: 24px;*/     }
/* #sort {

    margin: 10px 0;
  float:right;
  width:257px;
}
#sort span {display:none;}
#sort SELECT {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    color: #000;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  opacity:1 !important;
  float:left;

} */

button, textarea, input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea, input[type=text], input[type=password], select, .selector span {
  color: #888;
  font: 12px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
}

input[type=submit] { font: 12px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; }

textarea, input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 4px 8px;

}

button {
  background: transparent;
  color: #1b1e00;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

button, label, input[type=submit] { cursor: pointer; }



.selector span { display: block; }
.selector, .selector span, .selector select { cursor: pointer; }
```

And here is the css for what I would like it to look like:

```
/* all form DIVs have position property set to relative so we can easily position newly created SPAN */
form div{position:relative;} 

/* setting the width and height of the SELECT element to match the replacing graphics */
select.select{
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    width:166px !important;
    height:26px !important;
    line-height:26px;
}

/* dynamically created SPAN, placed below the SELECT */
span.select{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    float:left;
    left:0;
    width:166px;
    height:26px;
    line-height:26px;
    text-indent:10px;
    background:url(images/bg_select.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    cursor:default;
    z-index:1;
    }
```

Basically I don't know where anything goes. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Adding a jsfiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only browsers to fully support styling of dropdown menus is chrome. See this post:
[How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

If you need your drop downs to match cross browsers there are a couple options. 
1) http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/ or others like it (my usual pick),
2) Compeletly redesign a drop down from scratch. This is not recommended as is is very complicated and easy to create errors. see http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx 
or 
 http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/

Hope this helps!